# Plinq and linq performance comparison c#

Tags: c#, linq, plinq

Can someone explain for me why PLinq is better than normal linq in first example but worst in the second? I see the only difference is Thread.Sleep() at ExpensiveComputation() function

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace PlinqTest
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Salary { get; set; }
        public bool ExpensiveComputation()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            return (Salary > 2000 && Salary < 3000);
        }
        public bool NonExpensiveComputation()
        {
            return (Salary > 2000 && Salary < 3000);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Employee> employeeList = GetData();
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

            // Example 1

            stopWatch.Start();
            var linqResult = employeeList.Where<Employee>(e => e.ExpensiveComputation());
            int empCount = linqResult.Count();
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Time taken by old LINQ in Expensive Computation is {0} to get {1} Employees", stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds, empCount));
            stopWatch.Reset();
            stopWatch.Start();
            linqResult = employeeList.AsParallel<Employee>().Where<Employee>(e => e.ExpensiveComputation());
            empCount = linqResult.Count();
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Time taken by new PLINQ in Expensive Computation is {0} to get {1} Employees", stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds, empCount));
            stopWatch.Reset();
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Example 2

            stopWatch.Start();
            linqResult = employeeList.Where<Employee>(e => e.NonExpensiveComputation());
            empCount = linqResult.Count();
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Time taken by old LINQ in Non Expensive Computation is {0} to get {1} Employees", stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds, empCount));
            stopWatch.Reset();
            stopWatch.Start();
            linqResult = employeeList.AsParallel<Employee>().Where<Employee>(e => e.NonExpensiveComputation());
            empCount = linqResult.Count();
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Time taken by new PLINQ in Non Expensive Computation is {0} to get {1} Employees", stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds, empCount));
            stopWatch.Reset();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static List<Employee> GetData()
        {
            List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();
            Random random = new Random(1000);
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                employeeList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Employee" + i, Salary = GetRandomNumber(random, 1000, 5000) });
            }
            return employeeList;
        }
        static double GetRandomNumber(Random random, double minimum, double maximum)
        {
            return random.NextDouble() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

> Time taken by old LINQ in Expensive Computation is **5458.0269** to get 135 Employees
>
> Time taken by new PLINQ in Expensive Computation is **741.835** to get 135 Employees
>
> Time taken by old LINQ in Non Expensive Computation is **0.3653** to get 135 Employees
>
> Time taken by new PLINQ in Non Expensive Computation is **0.9175** to get 135 Employees

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. If you code is working, then you should go to [Code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The parallel version has to create and manage threads, and the NonExpensiveComputation is absolutely insignificant, so most of the time is spent managing threads.

Comment: @DavidGarcia this question includes all of this; are you sure you have read it before commenting?

Comment: @someone, the code is working so it is not a question for Stack Overflow. The user did not show us any research, he is just showing the code and results.

Comment: Thank for your replies. The code is working, but I can not understand why it has result like that.

Answer (score 1):

Parallelism is not free, it has a overhead cost to do. If the amount of work you are doing is very small that overhead cost can be more than the time savings you get.

I highly recommend reading the free E-Book [Patterns of Parallel Programming](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222), it talks about problems like the ones you are having and explains them fairly well.